# Between Two Datetime parameters not working properly SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

A particular result is not displaying properly using BETWEEN Statement

```
where [Column_name] >= @FromDate and [Column_name] <= @ToDate
```

Below is how I have set the values

```
DECLARE @Today AS datetime
DECLARE @FromDate AS datetime
DECLARE @ToDate AS datetime

SET @Today = GetDate()
SET @FromDate = @Today
SET @ToDate = DATEADD("dd", 7, @Today)
```

I found it was not working properly when I changed it from 7 to -7 and it was displaying an extra result which is not being displayed in the current query

Can you tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the result?

Comment: Its not displaying an order but its meant to be  @PatrickHofman

Comment: Can you give the full statement and the data? Possibly a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: @MohamedFareedh . . . You can put quotes around `dd`?  More importantly, what is the data type of the column?

Comment: It belongs to a company, so I am a bit scared about posting the query and the result. @PatrickHofman

Comment: @GordonLinoff I dont think thats it, because its displaying the results. Its just not displaying one of the order

Comment: Then obfuscate it a little.

Comment: I think its way I have done the Between statement @PatrickHofman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaron Bertrand has an extensive blog on why you should not use `between` with dates (see [here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)).

I am guessing from the names of your variables that you are forgetting about the *time* component on `getdate()`.  So, try declaring your variables as:

```
DECLARE @Today date;
DECLARE @FromDate date;
DECLARE @ToDate date;

SET @Today = cast(GetDate() as date);
SET @FromDate = @Today;
SET @ToDate = DATEADD(day, 7, @Today);
```

If you want to avoid `between`, you can write the comparison logic as:

```
where [Column_name] >= @FromDate and [Column_name] < DATEADD(day, 1, @ToDate)
```

EDIT:

In pre-SQL Server 2008 versions, the following removes the time component:

```
DECLARE @Today datetime;
DECLARE @FromDate datetime;
DECLARE @ToDate datetime;

SET @Today = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate()), 0); 
SET @FromDate = @Today;
SET @ToDate = DATEADD(day, 7, @Today);
```

Comment: I am getting an error stating I ahve declared an invalid datatype

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Microsfot SQL Server Management STudio- Version 10.0.1 @GordonLinoff

Comment: it worksss thankss, but  dont understand what this is doing DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate()), 0). Can you explain, thanks? @GordonLinoff

Comment: @MohamedFareedh . . . It is removing the time component on a date.  Don't worry about how it works . . . upgrade to a more recent version of SQL Server that supports the `date` data type.

Comment: I just don't understand why u r using DateAdd and DateDiff on the same expression..hence a bit confused haha. Thats why I want to know why u r doing that.

Comment: @freddy . . . The expression counts the number of days since "date" 0 and the current date/time.  It then adds these days -- an integer -- to 0, which has the effect of removing the time component.  But, as I say, in more recent versions of SQL Server you would just cast to a date.